# search and delete in text file

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to develop a Phonebook.

I write my contacts data to a text file and I work with console.  What options do I have to SEARCH and DELETE a contact in that text file?

This is how I am inserting contacts:

```
public class Writer
{
    public void  writer (string name,string lastname,string number)
    {
        StreamWriter Wrt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Sample.txt",true);
        Wrt.Write(name);
        Wrt.Write(lastname);
        Wrt.Write(number);
        Wrt.Write("#");
        Wrt.Write("");
        Wrt.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fine and dandy but what's your question. I hope you aren't expect us doing your homework, are you?

Comment: Here's a hint - use a consistent format or a delimited file for the data in your text file.  The search and delete algorithms will be much easier for you to implement.

Comment: Read the file into a list, remove the deleted contact and write it back out. Better yet put a _deleted_ flag on each record in the file and just overwrite the flag when the person is deleted. Then on add, check the flag and overwrite the first deleted person.

Comment: Or another hint - make e**X**tensive of use of a proven standardised for**M**at that will help you define the **L**ayout of your file to make it much easier to work with :)

Comment: I see this too often. Why do people always assume that when this kind of question is asked, that is it automatically for a homework? I might be like it might not be. Was the homework tag added by another user (I see it was edited)?

Comment: @Amaranth - Look at [the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10196153/revisions). The OP initially said in the question text that it is homework, then GETah added the tag, and I removed the text (because it was no longer necessary with the tag present).

Comment: @M.Babcock - Ok, sorry then ^^ I asked a question once, saying I was a software engineering student, and I specifically explained that it was not homework, but a project outside of class and someone tagged me with Homework...

Comment: @Amaranth - It is unlikely that the tagging was malicious. If you're learning to program then you'll likely benefit more from the soft hands of those that pay attention to the homework tag and the specific [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/174744) put in place for dealing with homework questions. If you have questions about the way we do things here, [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is a good place to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line correspond to a contact, right? What is your criteria to delete a contact? If you are looking for a name and lastname, you can do this.

```
string line = null; 
string Criteria = name + " " lastname;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input"))
{ 
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output"))
  { 
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    { 
      if (line.Contains(Criteria)) 
        continue; 

      writer.WriteLine(line); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

This will read your file and write all contacts you want to keep in another file.

However, if you want to keep the same file (or if your contacts info are on more than one line). You can read the whole file and keep it in memory, remove those you do not want, and then write the file again.

```
//Method with a class containing the info because informations are on several lines
Contact[] contacts = MethodToRead("filename.txt"); 
Contact[] filteredContacts = methodFilterContacts(contacts ); 
foreach(Contact c in filteredContacts)
{
     //Call your write method mentionned
     Writer.writer(c.name, c.lastname, c.number);
}

//Method if contact on only one line
string[] contactLines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt"); 
string[] filteredContactLines = methodFilterContacts(contactLines ); 
//This will write everything as is
File.WriteAllLines("filename.txt", filteredContactLines );
```

That was if you want to keep your text file. As it was suggested earlier, you can use xml to write and read an easier to maintain file. If you know the basics of xml, or up for a little challenge (and have time for it), it might be a better way to go.